# In Judaism do they believe that writting God's name is swearing an oath?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, nedarim-shevuot

I have recently asked a question about taking God's name in vain. And I have been told that swearing is taking his name in vain. So in teachings I see it mentioned G-d or Gcd. Showing to me a resistance of even saying the word "God". Why is this necessary? For when I say "God" I most likely am not swearing an oath. In Judaism do they believe that writing God's name is swearing an oath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different issues.
 1. Using a specific name of Gd when swearing an oath which is not allowed.
 2. Showing respect to any divine name.

[This link here](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/jewfaq/name.htm), will fully explain the how and why of writing Gd's name.  But the short version, is that writing Gd or G-d is in order to show respect to Gd and to not cause the name to be erased, or treated poorly.  It's unrelated to not using Gd's name in vain.